# Updating the list view items inside drawer

Tags: flutter, dart, state

This is a single page application.

I have created a drawer inside the Scaffold of HomePage. There are three list tile items in the list view below the title.

When I click the list tile I was able to change the title of the drawer through the `onTap` method.

But how can I replace the present list tile items with new list tile items after clicking any of the present list tile items.

In general how can I update the list tile items after pressing on any of the items in drawer

Before clicking an item

[image]

After clicking change font, the list is unchanged

[image]

What I want after clicking change font
[image]

I tried making a new function that returns a list view and called it in the `setState` inside `onTap` and also calling outside `setState` but inside the `onTap`

Comment: can you attach the picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: please consider including minimal code-snippet

Comment: hi @siddhesh-kumbhar , welcome to https://stackoverflow.com . please before ask the question read this guideline. your ask not have reproduce code and you will receive fewer responses.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a simple sample here, you can check it out if it satisfies your need.[Simple Drawer](https://gist.github.com/wiseminds/17c7f4db32389406ac5749008b2d610e)

you can run it on dart pad as well
[Dart pad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=17c7f4db32389406ac5749008b2d610e)

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    const Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue,
          ),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            drawer: const Drawer(child: MyDrawer()),
            body: Center(
              child: MyWidget(),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }

    enum MenuItem {
      font("Change Font",
          ['Commic Sans', 'Product Sans', 'Monserrat', 'ubuntu', 'unbounded']),
      theme("Change Theme", ['dark', 'light']),
      metrics("Change Metrics", ['small', 'medium', 'large']);

      final String label;
      final List<String> items;

      const MenuItem(this.label, this.items);
    }

    class MyDrawer extends StatefulWidget {
      const MyDrawer({super.key});

      @override
      State<MyDrawer> createState() => _MyDrawerState();
    }

    class _MyDrawerState extends State<MyDrawer> {
      MenuItem? selectedMenu;
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return SafeArea(
            child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                child:
                    Column(crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, children: [
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),
                  Text(
                    'Settings',
                    style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineMedium,
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 60),
                  Container(height: 1.0, color: Colors.grey),
                  const SizedBox(height: 60),
                  // if a menu item is selected, display its sub items
                  if (selectedMenu != null)
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, 
                  children: [
                    BackButton(onPressed: (){
                        setState(() {
                              selectedMenu = null;
                            });
                    },),
                    
                      for (var item in selectedMenu!.items)
                      InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            print(item);
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Text(
                                item,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                              )))
                  ])
                  else
                    for (var item in MenuItem.values)
                      InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              selectedMenu = item;
                            });
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: Text(
                                item.label,
                                style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodySmall,
                              )))
                ])));
      }
    }

    class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Text(
          'Hello, World!',
          style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineSmall,
        );
      }
    }
```